# Where do I put a TensorFlow model in a web application and how do I access it?

Tags: tensorflow, web-applications

I have a trained TensorFlow DNN model that I trained in Python but I saved it so I am able to access it through a Java program. I have no issues using the model with a regular Java application. I loaded the model using the following code:

```
SavedModelBundle bundle = SavedModelBundle.load("/scitweetsInfo/NeuralNetwork/scitweetsJavaModel/1514675940", "serve")
```

However, I'm not sure where to put the folder that contains the saved model in my Java web project. I'm also not sure what path I have to use to access it. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: So I found that if I put the absolute disk path ("D:/Github/....) it worked, so now I want to how I would do this without having to hardcode the disk path.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an api using flask(python). When you turn up the api make sure that you load the DNN model. When the API is hit, feed forward the network and return results or results path. Now the entire model is a REST api, hit the api with java web application.

Give the input to the flask api, get the result path and view on the web page.